# Is index or short transaction ID sent in getblocktxn messages?

Tags: message

Reading BIP152 I see that the Short Transaction ID is used in the *cmpctblock* message. Depending on whether the transaction is segwit or non-segwit, WTXID or TXID will be used to calculate its Short Transaction ID. What is not clear to me is whether *getblocktxn* meesage uses the index of the transaction or this Short Transaction ID?

In the BIP it is written that the getblocktxn message uses the following structure:

[image]

Based on that structure, indexes are sent.

However, the note for version 2 says the following:

> Short transaction IDs sent to us in cmpctblock messages, and sent by
> us in getblocktxn messages, are computed using the same process as in
> version 1, but using the wtxid as defined in BIP 141 instead of the
> txid.

**It is clear to me about *cmpctmessages*, but it says that the Short Transaction ID is also used in *getblocktxn* messages?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an erratum in that note in BIP152.

The `getblocktxn` message contains a BlockTransactionRequests, which contains a list of differentially encoded transaction indices (i.e., the difference between the position a given requested transaction has in the block minus the previous requested transaction's position, minus 1).

Comment: Thanks. About that differentially encoding. Does it mean that if I am sending indexes in `cmpctblock` or `getblocktxn` message for 0, 1, 34, 65, 137 and 258 transaction, I will encode it like 0, 0, 32, 34, 71 and 120?

Comment: No, as 0, 0, 32, 30, 71, 120.

Comment: Thanks. I made a mistake while calculating.